# Aqueous solutions of salts pH question

Tags: acid-base

I was reading up on [this](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Supplemental_Modules_(Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry)/Acids_and_Bases/Acids_and_Bases_in_Aqueous_Solutions/Aqueous_Solutions_Of_Salts#:%7E:text=Salts%20of%20weak%20bases%20and,water%20forming%20a%20hydronium%20ion.) "Aqueous Solutions of Salts" article on chemlibre and was doing problem 2 at the bottom:

**Question**: Find the pH of a solution of $\pu{0.200 M}$ $\ce{NH4NO3}$ where ($\mathrm{K_a} = \pu{1.8E-5}$).

**This is the given solution:**
$$\ce{NH4+ _{(aq)} + H2O_{(l)} <=> NH3 _{(aq)} + H3O+ _{(aq)}}$$
$$\frac{x^2}{0.2-x}=\frac{\pu{1E-14}}{\pu{1.8E-5}}$$
$$x=\pu{1.05E-5 M}=[\ce{H3O+}]$$
$$\mathrm{pH}=4.98$$

Why does this solution set $\frac{x^2}{0.2-x} = \mathrm{K_b}$ instead of the $
\mathrm{K_a}$? If I understand correctly, the equation in their solution is for the dissociation of an acid?

This is my work and where I got stuck:
[image]

I'm sure I'm just missing something here but any help would be appreciated!

Comment: **1)** We use the relation $\mathrm{K_aK_b=K_w}$, **2)** obtain $\mathrm{K_b}$, and **3)** use the equilibrium condition to find hydronium ion concentration. This is the method followed by the problem...

Comment: I understand the Ka and Kb relationship through Kw but am still confused as to why we use the Kb instead of the Ka in this problem, I thought since this is an acid dissociation we would use Ka.

Comment: is there a mistake in the question? $\mathrm{K_b}$ was supposed to be given, if you ask me...

Comment: Yes, there is a mistake, or a typo. The value 1.8e-5 belongs to Kb of NH3, not to Ka of NH4+. Therefore, the used Kw/Kb value correctly provides Ka of NH4+, that is needed for the approximation Ka =  [H+]^2/(c - [H+]).

Comment: Note that using photos/screenshots of text instead of typing text itself is highly discouraged.  The image text content cannot be indexed nor searched for, nor can be reused in answers.  Specifically handwritten scripts can be difficult to decipher.  Consider  copy/pasting or rewriting of essential parts. 
// You may find useful formatting guides for [texts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) and [formulas/equations/expressions](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here).

Comment: @Poutnik talking about canned notices it would be highly helpful if you could give the texts in Meta so that junior users like me can help the newbies out there.

Comment: @HarikrishnanM It would make them too official. Different users prefer different wording or put stress on different things. I keep mine handy on notes system at keep.google.com. and modify them often. Also having many variants, sometime combining or alternating them, some becoming obsolete, so they are dynamic. // If mods want them, I will provide them.